# I got some AWS CodeBuild Error. I have no clue to solve it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

*danke schoen* in advance

I'm newvie in AWS, especially I touched first AWS CodeBuild, CodeCommit... today.

and I got this Client Error in PROVISIONING phase

```
Unable to pull customer's container image. ErrorCode: 404 ~~~~
```

well, I guess I've set IAM Role properly, and of course I uploaded registry with my source(it's angular2 project)

I tried a lot of IAM role patterns (especially ec2 container service relevant roles...), and I tried building sources in AWS-based(recommaned) images and me-generated docker images(that's my goal)

but it failed all the way.

what do you think I did overlooked? what shoud I do?

Comment: As it looks for me - the client have unappropriated role. You can temporary grant "Allow all" permission and wait some time (1-2 min) for role population, to check this assumption. If so - then you should drill deeper in aws role permission mechanism.

Comment: There is a sample in aws codebuild documentation around accessing docker images from aws ecr http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-ecr.html

Can you validate step#3 (permissions) are correctly configured on the ecr repository.

Comment: thanks, #awsnitin. it really works. I really appreciated it. well AWS is still tricky for me, especially like this setting. I thought AWS authorities need the manual more explicit, like more simply seekable, or any slight head-up in the case of arraging CodeBuild like I did.

Comment: @awsnitin Can you make your comment an answer. It seems to be correct.

Answer (score 22):

Make sure you include "codebuild.amazonaws.com" as a Principal in your ECR permissions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-ecr.html

Comment: WHY IT NO SAY IN POLICY EXAMPLES ? Thanks a million btw.